# appended text will not display d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm hoping this is a simple issue,

I'm just trying to append a div to my svg which displays text. I have developed the code for this, and in the DOM it is showing that the my svg has the class attached, with the desired text inside. However, no text is appearing on the page.

I'm hoping someone will be able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Here is the code;

http://plnkr.co/edit/LxD1TarajR8dZUS7MbHg?p=preview

```
var vis = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", "svgCircle") //Append svg class
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

vis.append("circle")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
  .attr("stroke", "#dfe5e6")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr('r', width / 2)

d3.selectAll(".svgCircle") // append label to circles
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "circleLabel")
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label
  })
```

Comment: circles can't have children which are divs. You'd need to create a foreignObject child of the svg and put the div in that.

Comment: Alternatively lose the div and just output the text element (which will become a svg text element) as a child of the vis though, not the circle.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure how I would create a foreignObject child? This sounds like the better way, as I would have more control over the position of the text etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RobertLongson said you can only put html into svg with `foreignObject` (which doesn't work in IE).

Instead of this, I'd suggest going the svg way

Result: http://plnkr.co/edit/rb18RQTT7tBeo8lJXVpO?p=preview

```
d3.selectAll(".svgCircle")
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label
  })
  .style("stroke","black")
  .attr("dy", "1em");
```

You can control all the attributes of the text as opposed to your "*I would have more control over the position of the text etc*" comment. I just gave a `dy` and `stroke` attribute but you can color and shape your text whichever way you like

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to put a div inside an svg element and have it show up.

You probably want to use the `insert` function instead of `append`:
https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#insert

Comment: You can put a div inside a foreignObject inside an svg element